# Forward only email containing attachments

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, mail-forwarding

Is it possible to create rules on an exchange server so that if an email with an attachment is sent to `*@*.com`  the email will then be redirected to `**@**.com` and `***@***.com` ??

Google hasn't helped me :-/

Answer (score 3):

with the wizard in MS Outlook creating rules is trivial.

One rule for all messages with an attachment:

[image]

A second rule for all messages, except those with attachments:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion :) I knew it was possible to create the rules through Outlook - I was seeing if it was possible to create them on the exchange server for a users mailbox?

Comment: AFAIK those rules don't do anything special and will run server-side,  not dependent on Outlook being open. Me lazy. :)